# Hyperlink is showing as a STRING. Outlook Task for creating email holders

Tags: python, email, outlook, hyperlink, office-automation

I've tried all my luck, but I still can't figure out why my task.Body is not printing the Hyperlink that I want it to be.

I've tried changing it to HTMLBody, changing the bodyformat to 2 for it to be an HTML, Tried formatting it differently but I still get the same results.

I tried using HTMLBody but I get "property htmlbody cannot be set".

```
shortenedLink = f'<a href="https:/thelink{variable}">Hyperlink</a>' 

inviteItem.Body = shortenedLink
inviteItem.Save()
inviteItem.Display(true)
```

Comment: You need two slashes after `https:`, not just one.

Comment: apologies. It was just a typo. In my code, there are really two slashes.

Answer (score 0):

[TaskItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem) object does not expose the `HTMLBody` property the way `MailItem` object does, even though Outlook is perfectly capable of displaying HTML in the UI.

You have a couple of options:

1. Set the `TaksItem.RTFBody` instead. It is a binary (array) property, so the best way to figure out the value to be set is to take a look at an existing task with the RTF body set and use it as a template. At run-time, you can replace a placeholder and insert your own url in the array to be assigned to the `RTFBody` property. Note that OOM has a bug that prevents the `RTFBody` property from being set using late binding (like you'd be doing in Python or VBA), only early binding via the `TaskItem` interface works. You can take a look at the RTF body of an existing task with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select or open a task in Outlook, click IMessage button, select the `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` property.
2. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), it exposes `RDOTaskItem.HTMLBody` property.

Answer (score 0):

The `TaskItem` class doesn't provide the `HTMLBody` property. Instead, you need to use the `RTFBody` one if you want to use any formatting in the message body. The property returns or sets a `Byte array` that represents the body of the Microsoft Outlook item in Rich Text Format.

But there is a trick - to use `RTF` markup in the body of a task, simply try to use the `Body` property. Setting this property to a byte array containing *RTF* will automatically use that RTF in the body. Concretely, to get the body you want, you could use the following code:

```
task.Body = rb'{\rtf1{Here is the }{\field{\*\fldinst { HYPERLINK "https://www.python.org" }}{\fldrslt {link}}}{ I need}}'
```

Comment: This is so cool!! I've tried to print it, but it resulted in the HYPERLINK!! 

Just curious, could I also pass variables in the hyperlink here?

Comment: You can create a string dynamically by concatenating multiple strings and variables. Then just set the resulted string to the `Body` property.

Comment: Can I concatenate bytes and string? I can't seem to combine the two.

Comment: Nope, you can concatenate strings. You need to convert bytes to a string .

Comment: But when it comes to the hyperlink,  will it still work if I convert it into a string?

Comment: Does the code listed in my post work correctly?

Comment: It does convert it into a hyperlink. Unfortunately, I need to pass variables in that bytes. 

Example would be www.stack.com/{number}

is this possible?  How do I pass variables inside bytes?

Comment: In my post you can find a string, not bytes. Why do you want to use bytes instead?